# How to integrate $e^{-t^2}$?

Tags: integration

Anyone know how to integrate the following?

$$
\int_0^{+\infty} \! e^{-t^2} \, \mathrm{d}t
$$

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for answering and sorry for duplicating the question.

Comment: BTW I used this once as Turing test on the Google recruiter, after he send me email that was obivously a template, where the substitution had not worked.

Comment: By the way, I'm new to math stack exchange. How did you guys find out that this question was duplicated? Is there a clever way to search for equations / formulae in math stack exchange? Thanks.

Comment: I searched for "exp" and "e^" within my answers. You could try "e^{-t^2}" (with quotes) in the search box on the top right of the page.

Answer (score 0):

See this paper [link](https://www.unf.edu/~n00008500/Poisson.pdf).
In short: Go for the square, switch from rectangular to spherical summation, using spherical coordinates ("Trick of Poisson").

Note: Here is a slightly different version of the problem: [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1229251/can-anyone-clarify-why-this-is/1229275#1229275). It does not go to spherical coordinates explicitly but notes that the difference between integration over a square and over a circle vanishes for the dimensions going infinite.